# Can I use functions from another r package to calculate band values in rgee?

Tags: r, gis, rgee

I am working on creating a GEE Image Collection by compiling bands from various image collections to do band arithmetic with and calculate my final variable of interest. There are already GEE datasets for 2 of the 3 variables I need (cloud cover and artificial lighting), but for the 3rd variable (lunar intensity) I haven't been able to find anything. There is an r package called 'moonlit' that simulates lunar intensity for a given night at a given set of coordinates, so I want to use that to calculate the lunar intensity in each pixel of my template images and add that value as band 3. I wanted to use rgee for this because I was hopeful that I might be able to map the simulation function from the external moonlit package over an EE image collection directly, and not have to fuss around with importing and exporting large datasets, which is a pain. Has anybody done anything like this previously, or know if it is possible? And if it is possible, how do you do it?

So far I've been able to combine bands from the Sentinel 2 cloud probability product and the VIIRS Day/Night Band Monthly Composite, now I just need the moon values for the same pixels. I already know that S2 and VIIRS have different resolutions as well, but my plan is to use the pixels from VIIRS for moonlight calculations, then resample S2 to the same resolution (around 400m), because I think the 10m resolution of S2 will make the calculations take way too long.